# Android position view

Tags: android, overlay, positioning, android-relativelayout

In an application I have a relative layout with some content. What I need is to position a button over this content in such a way that it would always be stacked to the bottom of the display and in the center of its bottom border. Can someone give any suggestions of how to do that?

Comment: can u post some sort of snap,to understand clearly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these two lines to your button view xml:

android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"